# I need to close the menu, I added the option of not opening more than two submenus at the same time but now there is always one that remains open

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, backend

When adding the option to open only one sub-menu at a time, it generates the error that only one sub-menu should always be open and I do not understand the reason, I attach a test image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlff2.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv93I.png)

As you can see when one clicks it displays the menu but if I click it again it does not close but it opens again, in the image you see the closed arrow "↟" an up arrow and when the sub-menu opens the arrow changes down "↡", I say this to show the error that the menu never closes.

This is the html code
`

```
<nav class='animated flipInX'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <div class='fa fa-home'></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        About
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class='sub-menu'>
      <a href='#'>
        Products
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='sub-menu'>
      <a href='#'>
        Services
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        Contact Us
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

`This is the js code`

```
$(".sub-menu ul").hide()
$(".sub-menu a").click(function () {
    $(".sub-menu ul").not($(this)).hide();
    $(this).parent(".sub-menu").children("ul").slideToggle("200");
    $(this).find("i.fa").toggleClass("fa-angle-up fa-angle-down");
});
```

`
I ask for help to solve this problem, the idea is to let you close the normal menu but do not change the functionality of not being able to open more than one menu at the same time.

I tried many jquery options but I don't understand the error yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```js
$(".sub-menu ul").hide();
$(".sub-menu a").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("show")) {
        $(this).siblings("ul").hide();
        $(this).removeClass("show");
    } else {
        $(".sub-menu ul").hide();
        $(".sub-menu a").removeClass("show");
        $(this).siblings("ul").show();
        $(this).addClass("show");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class='animated flipInX'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <div class='fa fa-home'></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        About
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class='sub-menu'>
      <a href='#'>
        Products
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='sub-menu'>
      <a href='#'>
        Products2
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='sub-menu'>
      <a href='#'>
        Services
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        Contact Us
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Let open more than one at the same time.

Comment: It opens max two at the same time (as asked)

Comment: Maybe I explained wrong, sorry but the idea is that only one can be opened at a time, and that it can be closed without the need to be opened again.

Comment: Then it is damn easy.  Just edited the answer. Check now and please accept the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, with one `stack` keeping track of the open items. Easy to change the number of simultaneously allowed open sub-menus. The only addition is the `open` class (and the corresponding `CSS`).

```js
let stack = []

$(".sub-menu").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
    // if you click on a sub-menu, that is open
    // close it and remove it from the stack
    $(this).removeClass("open")
    stack = stack.filter((item) => item != this)
  } else {
    // if you click on a sub-menu, that is not open
    // open it and add it to the stack (as last item)
    $(this).addClass("open")
    stack.push(this)
    if (stack.length === 3) {
      // if the stack has 3 elements (actually, more than 2)
      // then remove the first element from the stack
      // and remove the "open" class from it
      const that = stack.shift()
      $(that).removeClass("open")
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.sub-menu>ul {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.open>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class='animated flipInX'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <div class='fa fa-home'></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        About
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class='sub-menu'>
      <a href='#'>
        Products
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='sub-menu'>
      <a href='#'>
        Products2
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='sub-menu'>
      <a href='#'>
        Services
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        Contact Us
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```